# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<400>

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Please solve the above error on the below code;
Please help me.

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/bookings/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json).header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtString)).andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
```

Comment: This error can mean anything - very generic("Bad request"). Usually it indicates some problem with the request itself. Make sure that the api exists, it accepts JSON data, that your payload is not malformed, and verify the Authorization header too. You want to check also if the server is working actually.

Comment: You should add more log for investigation. The status 400 only mean your request have a problem (maybe lack parameter or not enough information to serve)

Answer (score 0):

Generally 400 is Bad Request error it means the request you are sending is not proper which is expected by server.

So here the **json** is not proper so ensure that your json contains all the keys which are present in server side pojo class along with their type.

For troubleshoot in server side just ensure that controller method signature is all good like accepting json request and method type etc.